# Google Contacts for Thunderbird 38.6.0

Tags: 12.04

I have tried installing https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/google-contacts/ but I have only got a message 'Google Contacts could not be installed because it is not compatible with Thunderbird 38.6.0.' The site warns against using earlier versions of the 'Google Contacts'. Now, maybe I am finding a solution via gcontactsync.
   Tom

Answer (score 0):

I have installed https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gcontactsync/ and it appears to work.